# Merge отдельных файлов в ветку git

Tags: git, github, repository

Не могу разобраться как сделать merge отдельных файлов/папок в ветку.

У меня есть ветка main в которой лежат только source файлы, и есть две другие ветки, в которых эти файлы используются. Я бы хотел иметь возможность работать с ними из этих двух веток, и при этом поддерживать main в актуальном состоянии (нужно использовать актуальные source файлы полученные из ветки 1 в ветке 2 и наоборот), но я не могу понять как правильно сделать коммит в main, чтобы в него залетели только source файлы без всего остального ненужного в другой ветке мусора.

Comment: Видимо вместо отдельных веток надо было делать отдельные проекты.

Comment: Может я немного не понял, но разве вы не можете черипикать комиты в ветку майн из других веток?

Answer (score 1):

Разнесите все три ветки по разным проектам и main подключите в проектах 1 и 2 в качестве [подмодуля](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).